# Select nested array in array from an arugment in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array:

```
foo = [[51, 05,1.0],[51,979,0.18]]
```

What I would like to do is take this array and select all nested arrays that have the last value less than 1. So the output from the above would be

```
result = [[51,979,0.18]]
```

I have tried:

```
foo.select { |p| p.last < 1 }
```

But I get the error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `last'
```

The array is much larger than just two but I have listed the above as en example. I thought .select would be right, but I can not get it to work.

Comment: this code works, so probably one element in foo may is not an array at all.

Comment: Your error message should tell what class the receiver belongs to. Does it say that what you have is an array? And are you using an old version of Ruby?

Answer (score 3):

Your code works for me.

```
irb(main):007:0> foo = [[51, 05,1.0],[51,979,0.18]]
=> [[51, 5, 1.0], [51, 979, 0.18]]
irb(main):008:0> foo.select { |p| p.last < 1 }
=> [[51, 979, 0.18]]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you think bad values may exist in your data, it's worth protecting against them:

```
foo = [ [51, 05,1.0], [51,979,0.18], 4, nil, {:foo => :bar} ]

foo.select do |x|
    if (x.respond_to?(:last))
        x.last < 1
    else
        # the warn call evaluates to nil, thus skipping this element
        warn("#{x.class} does not respond to method last")
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

you were so close!
instead of p.last use p[-1]

so

```
foo.select{ |p| p[-1] < 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

what about this ?

```
foo.select { |p| p.at(-1) < 1 }
```

Comment: can you think of any reason why i get NoMethodError (undefined method `at' for

Comment: @CharlieDavies obviously because it's not an Array. You need to specify more information. `undefined method 'at' for` what exactly? the rest of the error message is there, please show it to us. Also, this code is no different from yours. array.at(-1) array[-1] and array.last all do the same thing